# Number of solutions to the quadratic congruence equation $5x^2+x\equiv y^2 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

By picking the values of $x$ first I got that the total number of solutions is $p+\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}\Big(\frac{5a^2+a}{p}\Big)$. Then I was told that it can also be $p-\Big(\frac{5}{p}\Big)$. I am very confused how $p-\Big(\frac{5}{p}\Big)$ is obtained.

Since I'm only a beginner in quadratic reciprocity please keep your solutions simple.

Comment: Completing the square, this is equivalent, when $\gcd(p,10)=1,$ to: $$(10x+1)^2-1\equiv 20y^2\pmod p.$$

Comment: How did you “notice” this if ou don’t know why? Is this a conjecture based on numerical evidence?

Comment: Your sum is a (variant of a) Gauss sum, and I'm guessing you could search around for a proof of its evaluation.

Comment: Yeah I tried to complete the square into $(10x+1)^2\equiv20y^2+1\mod p$, however I cannot see how it is related $p-\Big(\frac{5}{p}\Big)$......

Comment: Well, completing the square makes it obvious when $\left(\frac5p\right)=1,$ since $5\equiv b^2$ let’s us factor: $$1\equiv (10x+1)^2-20y^2\equiv (10x+1+2by)(10x+1-2yb)$$ and any of $p-1$ solutions to $uv\equiv 1$ we get unique $x,y$ with $$u\equiv 10x+2by+1, v=10x-2by +1.$$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Would you like to be more detailed? I think your answer is very close.

Comment: Sorry, I keep getting in trouble for helping people who don’t show enough work. @LianNuo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $(p,10)=1$. All congruences are modulo $p$.

After completing the square we have $(10x+1)^2 \equiv 5(2y)^2 +1$. Set $u = 10x+1$ and $v=2y$. Since this is invertible, the equation is equivalent to $u^2 \equiv 5 v^2+1$.

If $v \equiv 0$, we have $u \equiv \pm 1$, then we get $2$ solutions.

If $v \not\equiv 0$, write the equation as $(u\hat v)^2-\hat v^2 \equiv 5$ where $\hat v$ is the inverse of $v$ modulo $p$.

Factoring we have $(u\hat v+\hat v)(u\hat v - \hat v) \equiv 5$.

Now let $a = u\hat v+\hat v$ and $b = u\hat v - \hat v$ and we have $a b \equiv 5$.

From these equations we get $v \equiv 2\widehat{(a-b)}$ and $u\equiv (a+b) \widehat{(a-b)}$.

This proves each solution $(u,v)$ with $v \not\equiv 0$ is of this form.

Reciprocally, if we begin with a factorization $a b \equiv 5$ we can construct a solution $(u,v)$ using the formulas above as long as $a-b \not \equiv 0$.

There are $p-1$ factorizations of $5$ modulo p.

If $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=-1$ all this factorizations have $a \not \equiv b$. So in this case we have a total of $2 + (p-1) = p+1$ solutions.

If $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=1$ there are exactly two factorizations with $a \equiv b$. So in this case we have a total of $2 + (p-3) = p-1$ solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Where can I find more relevant materials? My number theory textbook doesn't cover much about this subject.